# cannot compile react js file using webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a file `app.js` that contains that record

```
handlePageClick = (data) => {
    let selected = data.selected;
    let offset = Math.ceil(selected * this.props.perPage);
    this.setState({offset: offset}, () => {
        this.setState({data: items.slice(offset, offset + 10), pageCount: 20})
    });
};
```

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this

var path = require('path');
    var node_dir = __dirname + '/node_modules';

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/js/app.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I am using [demo.js](https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate/blob/master/demo/js/demo.js) file as basis with minor adjustments. My `package.json` contains that dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "rest": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "react-paginate": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0"
  }
```

But when I try to start the application I get this error

```
[INFO] Module build failed: SyntaxError: .../src/main/js/app.js: Unexpected token (36:20)
[INFO]
[INFO]   34 |     };
[INFO]   35 |
[INFO] > 36 |     handlePageClick = (data) => {
[INFO]      |                     ^
[INFO]   37 |         let selected = data.selected;
[INFO]   38 |         let offset = Math.ceil(selected * this.props.perPage);
[INFO]   39 |         this.setState({offset: offset}, () => {
[INFO]
```

What is the problem? Wrong library version? Wrong `es`?

Comment: have you got `.babelrc` file ?

Comment: @Aaqib no. I only have `package.json` and `webpack.config.js`

Comment: add `.babelrc` in the root folder (where webpack.config.js is) , and just put this `{ presets: ['babel-preset-env', 'react'] }`  install babel-preset-env as a dev dependency , from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-env  because i believe currently its giving you syntax error as node does not recognise es6 syntax

Comment: Can add it to `loaders -> query` in `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: On my machine locally your code is not giving any error , i wonder if its some thing to do with resolve , add `resolve: {extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] }` after your module object

Comment: I added `babel-preset-stage-0` and it seems to started working fine

Comment: glad to know at-least its working now

Answer (score 0):

You need [babel-plugin-transform-class-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties)